# I'm trying to automate some solving equations in a macro

Tags: align, best-practices, automation

I'm trying to write a `macro` that will solve a `simple linear equation` and show all the steps but I"m having trouble writing a `macro`.  I'm resorting to copy and paste in every section. 
Here is what I am currently doing.  but I'm sure there is a better way.:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{examdesign}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xspace}
\SectionFont{\large\sffamily}
\usepackage[shortlabels,inline]{enumitem}  %%shortlabels here for matchign
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} %%%%%%%%%%%for marking angles
\usetkzobj{all}  %needed because Overleaf uses old version
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc,matrix}
\graphicspath{ {./dir1/} }
\usepackage{hyperref}
\Fullpages
\ContinuousNumbering
\ShortKey
%%\NoKey
\DefineAnswerWrapper{}{}
\NumberOfVersions{1}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%macro to round numbers
\newcommand*{\MyNum}[1]{%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[
        precision=1,
        fixed zerofill=false,
        ]{#1}}%
%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Macro for solvemyslope


    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\class{needed for examdesign}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%BEGIN DOCUMENT
%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{shortanswer}[title={Solving equations test},rearrange=no,resetcounter=yes]
\begin{question} Consider this question
\begin{answer}
\noindent
\begin{enumerate}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\linewidth}
\vspace{0pt}


    \newcommand{\firstx}{3}
     \newcommand{\bconstant}{4}   
         \newcommand{\firsty}{10}
    \item $mx+b=y$\\ $x=\firstx,b=\bconstant, y=\firsty$
%%%%%below is what I want automated.
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\bminusy}{\firsty-\bconstant}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myslope}{(\firsty-\bconstant)/\firstx} 
    \begin{align*}
        m(\firstx)+\bconstant&=\firsty\\
        -\bconstant&=-\bconstant\\
        \firstx m&=\MyNum{\bminusy}\\
        \frac{\cancel{\firstx}m}{\cancel{\firstx}}&=\frac{\MyNum{\bminusy}}{\firstx}\\
    m&=\boxed{\MyNum{\myslope}}
   \end{align*}
    \end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}
\end{answer}
\end{question}
\end{shortanswer}


\end{document}
```

Could someone instruct me on how to write a `macro` where I can use the values and have it automatically do the above code?
I imagine that it would look something like `\solvemyslope{x=3,b=4,y=10}` and it would write the `align` environment and fill everything in.
Right now `b` is only positive until I can figure out how to write this macro,
I'm guessing that I am using `pgfkeys` or something but I don't know how to set up the `macro`.  Someone help please.
This code will be repeated for parts `a, b, c` etc but I didn't have any problems because the `newcommands` were in `minipages`.  Maybe the `macro` should use provide command?  Anyways lost here, any help is appreciated and as always, any advice to better my code is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this? (just for integer coefficients and I hope it works)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*{\fracReducedTkz}[2]{\tkzReducFrac{#1}{#2}\ensuremath{\ifnum\tkzMathSecondResult=1
    \tkzMathFirstResult
    \else\ifnum\tkzMathSecondResult=-1
    \number\numexpr-1*\tkzMathFirstResult
    \else\ifnum\tkzMathSecondResult<0
    \frac{\number\numexpr-1*\tkzMathFirstResult}{\number\numexpr-1*\tkzMathSecondResult}
    \else
    \frac{\tkzMathFirstResult}{\tkzMathSecondResult}\fi\fi\fi}}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\newcommand{\solvemyslope}[3]{%
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{0}=1
    \begin{align*}
    #1 m+#2&=#3\\
    #1 m&=\number\numexpr #3-#2\\
    \frac{#1 m}{#1}&=\frac{\number\numexpr #3-#2}{#1}\\
    m&=\ifnum\number\numexpr (#3-#2)=0
    0\else\fracReducedTkz{\number\numexpr (#3-#2)}{#1}\fi
    \end{align*}
    \else
    Sorry it is Impossible!!
    \fi
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

    \solvemyslope{2}{2}{2}
    \solvemyslope{0}{2}{2}
    \solvemyslope{5}{2}{-2}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this looks good.  Thanks for your help.  I am looking for a way so that I can fit it all in one brace  and to ensure that I'm clear to say which value goes with each parameter  such as \myslope{x=2,b=3,y=7}.